# How to start a named NodeJS container with a named image from a docker-compose file and and a Dockerfile specifying the image?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Given this directory structure:

```
.
├── backend
├── compose.yaml
└── frontend
    └── Dockerfile.dev

2 directories, 2 files
```

My "compose.yaml" is like so:

```
services:
  frontend_service:
    container_name: frontend_container
    restart: always
    image: frontend_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile.dev
    working_dir: /home/frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/frontend
```

My "Dockerfile.dev" is like so:

```
FROM node:lts
```

But when I run `docker compose up --build -d` The `frontend_container` is constantly restarting and I cannot `docker exec -it frontend_container bash` into it to verify. I get this error message `Error response from daemon: Container 0136df5ba3c803dcded6695f65e51c38f4efe397859e77d001f862ced626d969 is restarting, wait until the container is running`

When I `docker ps --all` I get this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                        PORTS                           NAMES
0136df5ba3c8   frontend_image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago   Restarting (0) 1 second ago                                   frontend_container
9dbc74fa0bbb   postgres_image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 days ago      Up 33 minutes                 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp          postgres_container
f717459d3c53   pgadmin4_image   "/entrypoint.sh"         9 days ago      Up 33 minutes                 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   pgadmin4_container
```

You may be wondering why do I have such a weird compose file. But if you notice, I have a postgres container and a pgadmin container running. I tested this compose file structure with those two first before trying it out with node.

Given the directory structure in another project:

```
.
├── compose.yaml
├── pgadmin4.Dockerfile
└── postgres.Dockerfile

0 directories, 3 files
```

The "compose.yaml" is as follows:

```
services:
  postgres_service:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - db_network

  pgadmin4_service:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: pgadmin4.Dockerfile
    image: pgadmin4_image
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin4_volume:/var/lib/pgadmin
    networks:
      - db_network

volumes:
  pgadmin4_volume:
    name: "pgadmin4_volume"
  postgres_volume:
    name: "postgres_volume"

networks:
  db_network:
    name: "db_network"
```

And the "pgadmin4.Dockerfile" is as follows:

```
FROM dpage/pgadmin4
```

And the "postgres.Dockerfile" is as follows:

```
FROM postgres:latest
```

I essentially copied the compose file from the postgres/pgadmin project to the NodeJS project and made a few tweaks but the fact that the NodeJS container just crashes when I use docker-compose is just weird. If I use `docker run -d --name hello_node node:lts`, I can easily do `docker exec -it hello_node bash` just fine and `yarn --version` works just fine. Why can't I set up this workflow for NodeJS with docker-compose? Is it impossible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is because you do not have any running processes inside docker container of your `frontend_container`.

Comment: With the first Compose file you show, what benefit are you getting from using Docker?  It seems like you're just running an unmodified Node image against local code; you're not starting any other services, communicating with anything else, or building a reusable image.  Would using Node directly without Docker be a simpler setup?

Comment: Thanks for this. This is largely for my own learning/benefit - the end goal is to develop against a Dockerized NodeJS instance/container. Is it truly possible to use VSCode to develop a NodeJS backend and/or frontend (ReactTS) with a Docker container alone? You do make a valid point about using Node without Docker might be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `frontend_container` is not running any process with PID 1. Provide a command in your compose config for `frontend_service` so that the container does not exit immediately after you run it. This process could be any service, for isntance a dev server. In this example i am running a command `tail -f /dev/null`.

```yaml
services:
  frontend_service:
    container_name: frontend_container
    restart: always
    image: frontend_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile.dev
    working_dir: /home/frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/frontend
    tty: true
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

**PS:** After your container is running; login to the `bash` or `sh` of this container using `docker exec` command. Now if you run`$ top` command inside this conainter's shell your will find that `tail` command is running with PID 1. In docker this process is a main process and when it exits the container exists. I hope it clarifies you to figure out what to run in the `main` process inside docker container.

Comment: The container this produces won't be especially useful, since the `tail` process doesn't do anything.  I might recommend setting the `command:` to actually start the dev server (_e.g._, `command: npm run dev`), or better, `COPY` the code into the image and set its standard `CMD` there.  You should not need `docker exec` in typical happy-path usage.

Comment: Thank you @Lekhnath. Your solution worked. I wanted to try it out the `tty: true` and it still worked. What is the benefit of `tty: true`, if you don't mind?

Comment: @DeveloperInTraining https://kossy0701.medium.com/what-is-tty-true-in-docker-compose-yml-47a72891aee2

Comment: @DavidMaze That's why I said `in this example` in my answer. Who said `docker exec` is necessary?